# python - cx_Freeze shows error on a 64-bit os

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm converting my script in python to be an executable using cx_Freeze, it works fine after installing it on my on laptop(32 bit windows 7). After copying the .msi file and install it on my friend's laptop(64 bit windows 10), it shows this error.

I think the error is on the part of my script where I used 'win32com.client'. 
How can I make my system work on other platform? I'm new to this kind of stuff so I hope anyone will be able help me.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcskW.png)

**EDITED:**

Here's my setup.py script.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 
import sys
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6' 
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6'

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

if sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = "Win64GUI"

executables = [Executable("nafd.py", base=base,shortcutName="Nafd Encoding System",shortcutDir="ProgramMenuFolder", icon = "ntc96.ico")]


setup(
    name = "Nafd32",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages": ["time","win32com.client","tkinter","openpyxl","functools","os","datetime","re","requests","io","math"],"include_files":["newlistofcity.txt","newlistofbrgy.txt","newlistofbrgycode.txt","ntc96.ico","tcl86t.dll", "tk86t.dll"]}},
    version = "2.1.5",
    description = "Network and Facilities Division Encoding System",
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: I tried using pyinstaller in my script. It worked on my friend's laptop. I think the cx_freeze didn't include .dll from the win32com.client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by including all the `.dll` from the dist folder created by pyinstaller in my `setup.py`. I don't know why the cx_Freeze didn't copy the `.dll` files from `win32com.client` but pyinstaller copied all of them.